# How can I manipulate translation methods of cakephp 3 to become case insensitive?

Tags: translation, cakephp-3.0

This is a part of my src/Locale/en_US/default.po file

```
msgid "Acg_id"
msgstr "access control group identifier"

msgid "acg_id"
msgstr "access control group identifier"

msgid "Acg_Id"
msgstr "access control group identifier"
```

my default.po file is too long. And I think it is impossible to write like this.

```
msgid "Acg_id"
msgid "acg_id"
msgid "Acg_Id"
msgstr "access control group identifier"
```

How can I implement function below in cakephp core

```
function __($token){
    $translation = translation(strtolower($token));//translation returns translation of token if exists else returns null
    return $translation ? $translation : $token;
}
```

Then my default.po file will become too shorter :) like this

```
msgid "acg_id"
msgstr "access control group identifier"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think that case insensitive translations are kinda bad practice (why not simply use the proper message IDs?), you can easily pre-declare any of the [**shorthand translation functions**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.0/src/I18n/functions.php#L17) in your apps `config/bootstrap.php`, *before* including the autoloader.

```php
// [...]

use Cake\I18n\I18n;

// https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.0/src/I18n/functions.php#L26
function __($token, $args = null)
{
    if (!$token) {
        return null;
    }

    $arguments = func_num_args() === 2 ? (array)$args : array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
    // side note: you may want to use mb_strtolower instead
    return I18n::translator()->translate(strtolower($token), $arguments);
}


// Use composer to load the autoloader.
require ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';

// [...]
```

Comment: Thank you @ndm. How can I implement the proper message IDs? Is there a good tutorial?

Comment: @anghazighermezi What I ment with "proper", was to simply pass them correctly cased, it shouldn't be to complicated when they are all lowercased.