# What is the best way to add some codes before a function in cakephp3?

Tags: function, cakephp-3.0

I want to convert $token to lower case before I call the __($token) function.
How can I do this in a clean manner?

Possible solutions:

1. Manipulation the original function.

```
public function __($token, $args = null) {
    if (!$token) {
        return null;
    }
    $lowerCase = strtolower($token);
    $arguments = func_num_args() === 2 ? (array)$args : array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
    $translation = I18n::translator()->translate($lowerCase , $arguments);
    return $translation == $lowerCase ? $token : $translation;
}
```

I think it's not a good idea.

2. Using somethings like beforeFilter. It's better way.

3. Redeclaring function where I need. It's really bad idea :)

Any solution or best solution is appreciated.

Comment: [**Not the first time**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316489/how-can-i-manipulate-translation-methods-of-cakephp-3-to-become-case-insensitive) I hear that... why do the message strings need to be case insensitive in the first place?

Comment: I have seen that too :) But when I implement that solution, I encountered this error (Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in project\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\I18n\functions.php:26) in project\config\bootstrap.php on line 33).

Comment: why do the message strings need to be case insensitive in the first place? to stay the *.po file clean and short.

Comment: That is because you are defining the function too late. As mentioned in the answer, you have to declare it _before_ including the autoloader.

Comment: It can be clean and short even with case sensitivity, you just have to require proper message id usage in your code :)

Comment: I declared the function at the top of bootstrap.php and before including the autoloader as you mentioned. But still same error.

Comment: I kinda have my doubts... if you still receive the same error, that would mean that the autoloader is being included elsewhere.